# How Can I Access Elements By User Asset ID?

Tags: html

I am trying to click on elements on a page. While I was looking through the code for a good way to identify the element, I noticed that each different element had a different data-userassetid. How would I access this element?

```
<div class="item-card-container" data-userassetid="142946016">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `document.querySelector` and querying the elements by the attribute. The attribute query is the attribute name and value between brackets.

In that case:

```js
const userAssetElement = document.querySelector('[data-userassetid="142946016"]');
```

If you want to know more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector